# Can "way" be used as a verb?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

There are such lines in the song "Eyes of the World" ("Rainbow", a British rock band):

Evil moves, evil ways
With his back to the wall

and later

Evil takes, evil kills
With no shame or concern

Can "Evil" be a subject in all these cases with predicates "moves", "ways", "takes" and "kills"? In all online dictionaries "way" is a noun, but if it is a noun, "evil ways with his back to the wall" looks very weird. Can "way" be used as a verb here?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Song lyrics are not always grammatical. But I cannot read _ways_ as a verb, and therefore I read _moves_ as a noun as well and _evil_ as an adjective in that line. In the second line, I read _evil_ as a noun and the two as verbs - a formal paralellism without a grammatical one : effectively a [zeugma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma_and_syllepsis). Another possibility is that _ways_ is a mishearing for something else.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But could you clarify, why "his" is used in this case ("with his back to the wall")?

Comment: Dunno. Could refer to somebody yet to be talked about (cataphora). Why would Evil have his back to the wall?

Comment: Note the capital letters starting 'Evil' and 'With'. That means they are on _separate lines_. It is a poetry/song lyric convention to start a new line with a capital letter. Evil moves, evil ways (new line) Without seeing at all. The earlier line is to be considered by itself (as a comment).

Comment: Evil probably has his back to the wall to provide a rhyme for "Without seeing at all" two lines later.

Comment: Would the correct sentence be "With his back to the wall evil mind [is] looking down without seeing at all."?

Comment: Andrei, with poetry and song lyrics there is no "correct sentence".

Comment: It's definitely two lines, "Evil moves, evil ways / With his back to the wall".

Comment: They could also all be intended as nouns.

Answer (score 1):

> but if it is a noun, "evil ways with his back to the wall" looks very weird.

It looks weird, but it isn't.

Way / Ways **(noun)**

OED:

> **III. A course of action or behaviour; a means, a manner, a method.**
>
> **16.a. A path or course of life; a person's activities and fortunes in life, esp. when considered from an ethical or spiritual point of view.**
>
> **b. In plural. A person's habitual conduct viewed with regard to its morality.**
>
> 2006   Sight & Sound Sept. 48/1   *The message is: bullies must learn the errors of their ways by enduring a taste of their own medicine.*

**Move/ moves** is also a noun = movement; a premeditated action; a gambit.

> 2007 The Doctor Who Transcripts - The Infinite Quest DOCTOR: *Ah, ah, ah. Me first. (sotto) I thought Swabb would have made his move by now.*

Answer (score 0):

> Evil moves, evil ways With his back to the wall

I would interpret that to be saying "Evil moves *in* evil ways with his back to the wall".  "Ways" is not being used as a verb.  It's describing the *way* evil moves.  (And "Evil" is being "personified" here, hence the use of "his".)

Answer (score -2):

I don't think evil in this sentence is an adjective ''evil ways With his back to the wall'' Way (even tough it's apparently rare) has a verb version. 'Evil ways with his back to the wall ' you can consider this like '' Evil leans his back to the wall. ''